# Jasmine - Two spies for the same method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I'm new to `Jasmine` and I wanted to know if we can create 2 spies for the same method. Here is what I'm trying.

```
describe('something', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        mySpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('mySpy', 'functionInInterest');
        mySpy.functionInInterest.andCallFake(function (cb) {cb(something);});
    }

    //Some Test Cases
    describe('Here is the action!', function () {
        mySpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('mySpy', 'functionInInterest');
        mySpy.functionInInterest.andCallFake(function (cb) {cb(somethingElse);});
        //Some test cases that depends on somethingElse
    });
});
```

Testcases before `Here is the action!` depend on `mySpy.functionInInterest.andCallFake(function (cb) {cb(something);});` where as test cases inside `Here is the action!` depend on `mySpy.functionInInterest.andCallFake(function (cb) {cb(somethingElse);});`

**Note: Both have the same name**

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can do this, but maybe your problem is that you are overriding mySpy?

Comment: Ya sort of. Spy in beforeEach is being called rather the one in my describe/it

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
describe('Here is the action!', function () {
        mySpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('mySpy', 'functionInInterest');
        mySpy.functionInInterest.andCallFake(function (cb) {cb(somethingElse);});
        //Some test cases that depends on somethingElse
    });
```

do this

```
describe('Here is the action!', function () {
        mySpy_2 = jasmine.createSpyObj('mySpy', 'functionInInterest');
        mySpy_2.functionInInterest.andCallFake(function (cb) {cb(somethingElse);});
        //Some test cases that depends on somethingElse
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant change the name as its a angular service!

Comment: I know this is dead, but @Abilash, you want want to use this approach and the construct your Controller, Service, or Directive passing in your new spy object *after* you've created the object. After creating the spy object, you should make a function `createController()` where it will build the Controller/Service/etc with your new object created in `describe`