# Using Angular's di.js, how can I record the result of spies passed to the injector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Angular's dependency injection framework allows mock objects to be injected for testing purposes. The injector automatically instantiates objects passed to it before injecting them, so how can I record the internal workings of my code using a spy?

For example, in the below test I pass a `MockTransactionModel` into my system under test. I then wish to assert that the `description` field is equal to the same field in the request body (which I've mocked out), however, because the DI framework is creating an instance of the `MockTransactionModel` before injecting it, I have no reference to the actual object passed to `sut`.

```
describe('adding transaction', function() {
  var sut;

  beforeEach(function() {
    var injector = new di.Injector([MockTransactionModel]);
    sut = injector.get(TransactionController);
  })

  it('should save the description from the request body', function() {
    sut.add(mockRequest, null);

    expect(MockTransactionModel().description).toBe(mockRequest.body.description);
  });
});
```

In a sentence I suppose my question is: how can I can reference objects instantiated by the DI framework? I'm aware that I could simply inject my dependencies manually but I feel that somewhat negates introducing a DI framework.

#### MockTransactionModel

```
module.exports = MockTransactionModel;

var TransactionModel = require('../../app/models/transaction.model');
var di = require('di');

di.annotate(MockTransactionModel, new di.Provide(TransactionModel));

function MockTransactionModel() {
  return {
    description: '',
    amount: 0
  }
}
```

#### TransactionController (SUT)

```
module.exports = TransactionController;

var di = require('di');
var TransactionModel = require('../models/transaction.model');

di.annotate(TransactionController, new di.Inject(TransactionModel));

function TransactionController(transactionModel) {

  this.add = function(req, res) {
    transactionModel.description = req.body.description;
    transactionModel.amount = req.body.amount;
  };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Provider dependency injection - using $log in provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620927/angularjs-provider-dependency-injection-using-log-in-provider)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine - Two spies for the same method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437035/jasmine-two-spies-for-the-same-method)